# How to install weblogic maven plugin for weblogic v12.1.2 (12c)?

Tags: weblogic12c, weblogic-maven-plugin

To install weblogic application server I decompressed 2 files I got from or oracle using these links:

http://download.oracle.com/otn/nt/middleware/12c/wls/1212/wls1212_dev.zip
http://download.oracle.com/otn/nt/middleware/12c/wls/1212/wls1212_dev_supplemental.zip

..found on [this page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/ias/downloads/wls-main-097127.html).

I simply decompressed both files and they automatically decompress to the same folder. setting the `MW_HOME` and `JAVA_HOME` environment variables to point to the decompressed folder and Java 7 JDK locations respectively, I ran the `configure.cmd` file and it ended successfully.

The problem is that I can't reach the same result [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/WLPRG/maven.htm) shows if I follow the instructions on it. I summarized these instructions here:
(`ORACLE_HOME` is identical to `MW_HOME`, they both point to the installation folder.)

```
%ORACLE_HOME%/wlserver/server/bin/setWLSEnv
cd %ORACLE_HOME%/oracle_common/plugins/maven/com/oracle/maven/oracle-maven-sync/12.1.2
mvn install:install-file -DpomFile=oracle-maven-sync.12.1.2.pom -Dfile=oracle-maven-sync.12.1.2.jar
mvn com.oracle.maven:oracle-maven-sync:push -Doracle-maven-sync.oracleHome=D:/oracle_home
mvn help:describe -DgroupId=com.oracle.weblogic -DartifactId=weblogic-maven-plugin -Dversion=12.1.2-0-0
```

Where `oracle-maven-sync.oracleHome` is `The path to the Oracle home that you wish to populate the Maven repository from.`. Its basically the Weblogic directory having `wlserver` directory in it.

The problem is that the last line (the line that asks the installed plugin for description), shows the following error message (Ignore the masked IPs, I masked them manually in this question):

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] Using the builder org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder with a thread count of 1
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-help-plugin:2.2:describe (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
[WARNING] The POM for com.oracle.weblogic:weblogic-maven-plugin:jar:12.1.2-0-0 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.775 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-05-04T13:00:03+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/152M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:2.2:describe (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Plugin does not exist: Plugin could not be found, please check its coordinates fo
 typos and ensure the required plugin repositories are defined in the POM
[ERROR] com.oracle.weblogic:weblogic-maven-plugin:maven-plugin:12.1.2-0-0
[ERROR]
[ERROR] from the specified remote repositories:
[ERROR] central (http://x.x.x.x:xxxx/artifactory/plugins-release, releases=true, snapshots=false),
[ERROR] snapshots (http://x.x.x.x:xxxx/artifactory/plugins-snapshot, releases=true, snapshots=true),
[ERROR] central-se (http://x.x.x.x:xxxx/artifactory/plugins-release, releases=true, snapshots=false),
[ERROR] snapshots-se (http://x.x.x.x:xxxx/artifactory/plugins-snapshot, releases=true, snapshots=true)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

What makes me think that this is NOT a network problem, is that I've successfully installed this plugin before, but I can't remember how exactly so may be I'm missing some steps ?

How can I resolve this please ? My goal is to be able to refer to weblogic's libraries from maven as a **dependency** in the following way:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.weblogic</groupId>
    <artifactId>weblogic-server-pom</artifactId>
    <version>12.1.2-0-0</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer is on [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/core/MAVEN/config_maven.htm#CDCIBGJA) which mentions how to install weblogic's maven dependencies in the local repository. For installing them on the remote repository, follow the instructions [in this section](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/core/MAVEN/config_maven.htm#CDCGICIJ).

For quick reference, I had to run this command (Please read the comments after the command before running it):

```
mvn com.oracle.maven:oracle-maven-sync:push -Doracle-maven-sync.oracleHome=%ORACLE_HOME% -Doracle-maven-sync.testingOnly=false
```

Where `-Doracle-maven-sync.oracleHome` represents weblogic's installation folder. Its a folder that should hold directories like and not only:

- oracle_common
- user_projects
- wlserver

In my question I already ran the plugin `mvn com.oracle.maven:oracle-maven-sync:push` but I didn't specify the parameters mentioned here.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [WebLogic 12.1.2 documentation page](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/WLPRG/maven.htm#CHDCBBIJ), follow these instructions:

> 1. Install the Oracle Maven sync plug-in and run the push goal:
>
>    - Change directory to *ORACLE_HOME\oracle_common\plugins\maven\com\oracle\maven\oracle-maven-sync\12.1.2*.
>    - mvn install:install-file -DpomFile=oracle-maven-sync.12.1.2.pom -Dfile=oracle-maven-sync.12.1.2.jar.
>    - mvn com.oracle.maven:oracle-maven-sync:push -Doracle-maven-sync.oracleHome=c:\oracle\middleware\oracle_home.
> 2. You can validate whether you have successfully installed the plug-in using the Maven help:describe goal. See the Apache help
>      plug-in describe goal documentation for additional information.
>
>    - mvn help:describe -DgroupId=com.oracle.weblogic -DartifactId=weblogic-maven-plugin -Dversion=12.1.2-0-0

Comment: Thank you but you can see that I mentioned in my answer that I've already tried that. The problem was that the commands I tried didn't populate my maven repository with weblogic's dependencies. I've posted an answer with the command to do so. Thanks again.