# Maven: Error putting Weblogic libs into local repository

Tags: oracle, maven, weblogic12c, weblogic-maven-plugin

I want to put Weblogic libs into local repository (Installing and Configuring Maven for Build Automation and Dependency Management) I have the Weblogic version is 12.1.2 installed in my workstation.

I run this command:

```
mvn -X com.oracle.maven:oracle-maven-sync:push -Doracle-maven-sync.oracleHome=C:\Oracle\product\11.2.0\client_x86 -Doracle-maven-sync.testingOnly=false
```

but I got this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.oracle.maven:oracle-maven-sync:12.2.1-2-0:push (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Synchronization execution failed: 
No resources were processed by the sync plugin -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.oracle.maven:oracle-maven-sync:12.2.1-2-0:push (default-cli) 
on project standalone-pom: Synchronization execution failed
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Synchronization execution failed
        at com.oracle.maven.sync.ODMPushMojo.execute(ODMPushMojo.java:242)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: com.oracle.maven.sync.SyncException: No resources were processed by the sync plugin
        at com.oracle.maven.sync.ODMPusher.handleError(ODMPusher.java:458)
        at com.oracle.maven.sync.ODMPusher.push(ODMPusher.java:117)
        at com.oracle.maven.sync.ODMPushMojo.execute(ODMPushMojo.java:240)
        ... 22 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

C:\Users\carbonell>
```

Answer (score 3):

This may be an old thread, but the answer may still help somebody

**Cause:**
Issue was happening due to wrong variable -Doracle-maven-sync.oracleHome

**Solution:**
Please change the flag to `-DoracleHome:`

```
mvn -X com.oracle.maven:oracle-maven-sync:push -DoracleHome="your Oracle home dir" -Doracle-maven-sync.testingOnly=false
```

Answer (score 1):

Your ORACLE_HOME points to the Oracle data base driver. I think you need to point it to the Oracle Middleware (aka Weblogic) directory.

Answer (score 1):

Check that you refer to weblogic's libraries from maven as a dependency in the following way:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.oracle.weblogic</groupId>
  <artifactId>weblogic-server-pom</artifactId>
  <version>12.1.2-0-0</version>
  <type>pom</type>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Then, you must try this, [from this reference](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/core/MAVEN/config_maven.htm#CDCIBGJA):

```
mvn com.oracle.maven:oracle-maven-sync:push -Doracle-maven-sync.oracleHome=%MW_HOME% -Doracle-maven-sync.testingOnly=false
```

If nothing works, see also [this very related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23455631/how-to-install-weblogic-maven-plugin-for-weblogic-v12-1-2-12c)

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling for a week for same problem.
Finally it is solved.

```
mvn com.oracle.maven:oracle-maven-sync:push -DoracleHome=<wls_home>
```

for my system:

```
mvn com.oracle.maven:oracle-maven-sync:push -DoracleHome=<put here your local path>/Opt/Oracle/WebLogic/Middleware/wls12213
```

Comment: Yes, confirming that this is a correct answer. The -DoracleHome parameter must point to the directory where WebLogic is installed. For example, for WebLogic 12.1.3 this directory contains 'wlserver', 'oracle_home' (as well as other subdirectories) and the 'configure' sh and cmd scripts.